# Reading images with OpenCV multithreaded does not work

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I have a Python code that will read images from the hard drive in parallel. Each Thread will read a different image. I get a vector that has all of the paths. The paths are correct since I am able to load the images when it is not done threaded. However, not all Images are read, the result from reading the images multithreaded are looking rather sparse.

To get the result from threads I initialize a vector filled with `None` like this `RGBS_of_Threads = [None]*len(rgb_imgs_path)` , where the amount of expected images is described with `len(rgb_imgs_path)`. However after waiting for the threads to join I only get some images and not all.

```
import cv2
from threading import Thread

#Threading Target
def parallelRead(RGBS,path,i):
   RGBS[i] = cv2.imread(path[i])

#Some Setup where the path is from  
rgb_imgs_path = getPaths()

###Simple Program loop
RGBS_of_loop = [None]*len(rgb_imgs_path)
for i in tqdm(range(0,len(rgb_imgs_path))):
    RGBS_of_loop[i] = cv2.imread(rgb_imgs_path[i])


#Check if it worked
if None not in RGBS_of_loop and RGBS_of_loop is not None:
    print("reading from loop was successfull!")
else:
    print "amount of Nones" + str(RGBS_of_loop.count(None))
    print "total length" + str(len(RGBS_of_loop))


#Now with threading
RGBS_of_Threads = [None]*len(rgb_imgs_path)
threads = []
for i in tqdm(range(0,len(rgb_imgs_path))):
    threads.append(Thread(target=parallelRead,args=[RGBS_of_Threads,rgb_imgs_path,i]))
for i in tqdm(range(0,len(rgb_imgs_path))):
    threads[i].start()
for i in tqdm(range(0,len(rgb_imgs_path))):
    threads[i].join()

#check if it worked
if None not in RGBS_of_Threads and RGBS_of_Threads is not None:
    print("reading from thread was successfull!")
else:
    print "amount of Nones" + str(RGBS_of_Threads.count(None))
    print "total length" + str(len(RGBS_of_Threads))
```

Comment: You might get better performance and actually parallel reading using multiprocessing rather than threading.

Comment: That's true but it was harder for me to implement the memory mapping. However this code occupies all 16 cores available to me, so I think that multiprocessing will not increase it roughly, don't you think? Anyhow - this will not fix the original problem I guess?